# Pass down router to child components via context

Tags: react-router

I am trying to pass down the Router via context, so I can call navigateTo on a child React.Component.

Purpose:
I need to navigate away from login when I have a successful login.
Strategy:
1. Passdown Router to childe login component.
2. When successfully login call navigateTo('/startpage') on Router passed down.

I have this on the page/component that contains the Run:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

The following context setup:

```
getChildContext() {
    return {
        router: Router
    };
}
```

and this for childContextTypes:

```
childContextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

And for the child itself:

```
contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

The context setup works fine if I am using `"router: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired"`. Note strings, but when using object I get:

But when I try to use object I get Errors:

> Warning: Failed Context Types: Invalid context 'router' of type 'object' supplied to 'NavItemLink', expected 'function'. Check the render method of

and:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.context.router.isActive is not a function

Any help is welcoming?

Comment: Can you post the applicable routes? Have you thought about making a function on the parent component like `loginSuccessful()` that handles the router transition and pass that down to the child component via props?

Comment: Hi Brad. Yep, that was exactly what I did :-) Thanks anyway. I will click this as useful - I dont know if that gives any points, but still.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to create a function on the parent and pass that down with context.

Parent:

```
contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
```

and on child components:

```
childContextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just passing along `router`, then look at wrapping your component in the Higher-order Component `withRouter` available [starting in v2.4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md).

Numerous examples within the `react-router` repository use this, here is one example:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js#L9